# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'angular' is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my controller.js has the following code:

```
  var myController = angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
```

My Services.js has the following code:

```
  angular.module('myApp.services', [])
```

When I run my application, the code "var myController = angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])" gives me the following exception:
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'angular' is undefined.

Can anyone please tell me what goes wrong? Your help will be appreciated :)

Btw, here is the html code of my web app

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PathFinding.js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./lib/themes/jquery.ui.all.css" />
    <script src="./js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/bower_components/pathfinding/pathfinding-browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/state-machine.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/async.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/ui/jquery.ui.slider.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/pathfinding-browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/view.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/Services.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/mainApp.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/panel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <ion-modal-view>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-scroll zooming="true" overflow-scroll="false" direction="xy" style="width: 100%; height:100%;"
                        scrollbar-x="false" scrollbar-y="false">

                <div class="scroll-container" id="draw_area" style="width: 100%; height:100%; background: url('PathFindingMap.png') no-repeat ">
  
                </div>
            </ion-scroll>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-modal-view>

    <button style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:30px;margin-right:30px;" id="button1" class="control_button" type="button">Search!</button>

    <div style="visibility: hidden;" id="algorithm_panel" class="panel right_panel">

        <div class="accordion">

            <h3 id="astar_header"></h3>

            <div id="astar_section" class="finder_section">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="visibility: hidden;" id="play_panel" class="panel right_panel">

    </div>
    <div id="stats"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like angular javascript didn't load yet

Comment: can you show me full code

Comment: Hi @Icepickle, angular javascript didn't load yet?

Comment: tell your <script src ...> line

Comment: Hi, I have the following codes in my index.html.                                            <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/Services.js"></script>                 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

Wrong approach of building your angular app
This is how you need to define your module

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
```

This is how you need to add your controller in your controller.js
As you have already define your module,no need to give dependency

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp')
app.controller('myController',function(){
// Here is your controller content
})
```

Here is how you need to add your service in service.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp')
app.service('myService',function(){
// Here is your service content  (this.method);
})
```

Your code gives you error because you have defined your module 2 times, ie defining its dependency `[]`

Comment: Hi @Parshuram, I created a new file named "mainApp.js". This file contains the following code: var app = angular.module('myApp', []). And I have followed your instruction. However, I received this error:    Unhandled exception at line 20, column 488 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:nomod] 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp

Comment: Please add your code with the HTML file where you included all this file and used angular controller

Comment: Hi @Parshuram, I have added my html code in the Question.

Comment: First add your mainapp.js after that controller and service add a controller in your div, ng-app=myapp and ng-controller = "mycontroller"

Comment: Also I am not seeing any angular.js

Answer (score 0):

On your controller.js try to reference the angular.js script.

Simply drag the angular.js to you controller.js file. You code will look like this.

```
/// <reference path="../../../scripts/angular.js" />
```

On your html code. Include the angular.js and put it into first hierarchy then add your controller.js or else your code will not work.

```
<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controller.js"></script>
```